# JSON error when using express/node/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Anyone know this error? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dAq9.jpg

"Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0...

I don't know how an error message can get any more vague. I also followed a guide which apparently has worked for many people but for whatever reason I run into this error...

This is the guide I followed verbatim. https://youtu.be/8bNlffXEcC0

And I also followed other guides that are the same thing

But I keep running into this weird error message when it's time to display.

I'm guessing I have a weird version of node or something?

Comment: Your backend likely doesn't return a valid JSON, or doesn't return JSON at all

Comment: You may consider not to start every sentence from new line, so it doesn't look like poetry.

Comment: `/users` isn't returning a valid JSON, show us your `users` route so we can help you.

Comment: Here is what my `/users` returns https://imgur.com/a/9Lxi7pC

Comment: What the value of `proxy` inside your `package.json` ?